# Finding general solution with reduction of order method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution by using reduction of order method to $$t^2y''-ty'-3y=0$$given that $y_1(t)=t^3$ is a solution.

Comment: substituion $t=e^z$

Comment: Please show how far you got, starting with $y_2(t)=u(t)y_1(t)$.